# List connected network folders

Tags: samba

Does any one know how can I list this remote folders mounted on nautilus?

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:
[List samba shares and current users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102924/list-samba-shares-and-current-users)

[shared folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADHpT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@N0rbert comment answers the question.

What I basically have to do is `ls /run/user/$UID/gvfs`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use gio (VFS API) command:

```
gio mount -l
```

this command lists all mount type (disks, partitions, etc), if you want only samba shares, then use grep to filter:

```
gio mount -l | grep smb
```

[gio reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/ch01.html)

Comment: It looks like `gio` is a tool that comes with GNOME and I am using Unity. Couldn't  manage to install it :(