# Equivalent of Windows net use (list) for connected samba shares

Tags: networking, samba

What is the equivalent CLI command to list all currently connect smb shares from the client perspective.

Like :

```
C:\> net use
Status        Local           Remote                     Network
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK            Z:              \\backupsrv\users          Microsoft Windows Network
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List samba shares and current users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102924/list-samba-shares-and-current-users)

Comment: @FedKad: That link contains information regarding how to tell what client shares are being used from the server.  I need to know what shares my current client is connected.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single command to do that since you can mount the share two different ways. If you mount with cifs ( as in mount.cifs ) you can do a `mount | grep cifs` . If you are mounting it from Nautilus the shares are mounted at `ls -l /run/user/$UID/gvfs`

Comment: @Morbius1. The shares didn't show with mount but did show with ls -l /run/user/$UID/gvfs.  Thanks. That will do!  CAJA must do the same!

Comment: @Morbius1: The reference to gvfs sent me on the correct path!!!

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
$ gio mount --list
or
$ gio mount --list | grep smb
```

[Mount SMB share with gvfs from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712290/mount-smb-share-with-gvfs-from-command-line)